# How can I remove dither effect on player's shadow?

Tags: unity, shadows, unity-shader-graph

I am trying to make a dithering effect on the player so that when the camera comes below or very close to the player he will be dotted or transparent like in Genshin Impact. So, I followed a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVeS7oh3oug) and created this shader graph:

[image]

It works when I get close to the player, the problem is that if I set `ditherOffset` to a value different than `0` and `ditherRange` to a value different than `1` the shadow will have holes in it like this:

[image]

The more I alter them, the more it fades. So, how can I fix this? Is it possible not to apply the dithering effect on the shadow?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options.

Probably the best one is to [use the technique shown in this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/alpha-clip-dither-and-keep-original-shadows.781412/), where the dithering effect is disabled for the shadow pass with an `#ifdef` check. Here's how to write that in a graph using a Custom Function node:

[image: Custom IsShadowCaster function]

If you are using HDRP, there is also a parameter called [Shadow Threshold](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@12.1/manual/Alpha-Clipping.html) which sets a separate clipping threshold specifically for the shadow pass. I'm not sure if something similar exists for the other RPs.

And lastly, the nuclear option is to duplicate the mesh, have the "normal" mesh not cast shadows at all, and set the duplicate (with a separate material that does not have dithering) to only cast shadows and not be rendered otherwise. But this is the worst option, in my opinion.